# jQuery n times .append($('<td></td>')) = less than n columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var user = {};
var row = $('<tr></tr>')
   .append($('<td></td>').text(user ? user.call_id : ''))
   .append($('<td></td>').text(user ? user.phone_number : ''))
   .append($('<td></td>').text(user ? user.dialed_number : ''))
   .append($('<td></td>').html(user && user.admin ? '<span class="textgreen">admin</span>' : 'guest'))
   .append($('<td></td>').append(_talking(user ? user.mute : 0)))
   .append($('<td></td>').append($('<span></span>').addClass('timer').text(user ? user.duration : '')))
   .append($('<td></td>').addClass('nowrap').append(_userButtons(user)))
;
alert( row.find('td').size() );    // = does NOT always alert 7, but a smaller value
```

Why is that so?

At the moment, `user.dialed_number` is `undefined`, therefore the missing column is the third one. And it doesn't matter how much I repeat that column, the result is always `6` in my project.

** **UPDATE** **

Here is a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ry6XW/) showing the problem; it should output `7`, but it shows `4`

Comment: what does it look like when you firebug it?

Comment: What's the content of user.dialed_number look like?

Comment: it does not really matter. It seems that `.append($('<td></td>')).append($('<td></td>'))` actually only appends one `TD` element... (see jsfiddle)

Comment: Can you `alert()`, or `console.log()`, the various variables and check that they're all assigned as you expect?

Comment: that's the thing, they don't have to be assigned right away; the row and columns are updated later on. But all the columns should be present!

Comment: A simplified case ( http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/Ry6XW/1/ **AND** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/Ry6XW/2/ **AND** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/Ry6XW/4/ **AND** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/Ry6XW/5/ ) shows 7. I suspect something else is going on here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any one of the expressions passed to `.text()` evaluates to `null` or `undefined`, the call to `.text()` will return the text of the `TD` - which is nothing - instead of the jQuery collection representing the `TD`. So you'd append 6 `TD`s and a nothing.

Answer (score 3):

AHA!

```
$('<td></td>').text(undefined)
```

is the same as

```
$('<td></td>').text()
```

Which as per the jquery document for [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text1) (look at the top right of the doc) it returns the text inside the element. Then you append that text (which is an empty string) to the `<tr>`.  And that is why the `<td>` is not appended

Simple fix:

```
$('<td></td>').text((true ? undefined : 'false') || '') // oops should  be ||
```

will do an empty string when the first part can be coerced to null (like undefined, 0, null, '', and 0.0)

Proof of concept: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek35m/)

Answer (score 2):

You're checking that the `user` exists each time, but not checking if the property exists which is returning `undefined` and making your statement append the contents of the `td` (which is nothing) instead of the `td` itself.

If you change your tests to check for the property instead, it works:
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/Ry6XW/6/)

Answer (score 1):

In your jsfiddle, the reason it is only showing 4 is that the properties on `user` are not defined.

Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvkM3/)

Maybe your user properties are not defined?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you stop trying to be quite so clever and single-step each `append` and see what's happening, rather than trying to do it all in one line. For one thing, it probably isn't doing what you think it should be doing anyway the way you wrote it - each `td` is getting inserted INSIDE the previous one!

Try this way:

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>');
row.append($('<td></td>').text(user ? user.call_id : ''));
row.append($('<td></td>').text(user ? user.phone_number : ''));
row.append($('<td></td>').text(user ? user.dialed_number : ''));
row.append($('<td></td>').html(user && user.admin ? '<span class="textgreen">admin</span>' : 'guest'));
row.append($('<td></td>').append(_talking(user ? user.mute : 0)));
row.append($('<td></td>').append($('<span></span>').addClass('timer').text(user ? user.duration : '')));
row.append($('<td></td>').addClass('nowrap').append(_userButtons(user)));

alert( row.find('td').size() );    // = alerts 6 when it should be 7
```

Also, when I run your code even with your crazy syntax (after ensuring that all functions and variables are defined and exist) I get 7.

Comment: This is not true.  The TDs are not getting inserted inside eachother, `append` returns the original object, not the appended one.

Comment: The TDs do not get inserted inside the previous.  `.append()` returns the collection on which it was called. The problem with his shortcut syntax is not in the chaining--jQ was built to do that. It is in the ternary conditionals and what they eval to. That said, you're right that breaking it out into many steps or more verbose code is the first step in debugging the problem.

Comment: "_after ensuring that all functions and variables are defined and exist_" - therein lies the crux of the problem: not all the properties of `user` exist, which is appending an empty string.  Nothing to do with the `append()` syntax, which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

The script appends the cell to the previous cell, not the row. $.end() returns the selected object at the beginning of the chain, i.e.:

```
    $('tr', this).append($('<td>').text(user ? user.call_id : ''))
                 .end().append($('<td>').text(user ? user.phone_number : ''))
                 .end().append($('<td>').text(user ? user.dialed_number : '')) //etc.
```

Comment: No, that's not true.  `.append()` returns the collection on which it was called, thus this chaining of appends is reasonable.

Comment: Not true.  `append` returns the original object and not the one being appended.

Answer (score 0):

corrected version

```
function _talking() {
    return $('<span>TalkingFn</span>');   
}
function _userButtons() {
    return $('<button>button1</button><button>button2</button>');   
}

var user = {};

var row = $('<tr></tr>')
    .append($('<td></td>').text(user.call_id ? user.call_id : '{calli_id}'))
    .append($('<td></td>').text(user.phone_number ? user.phone_number : '{phone_number}'))
    .append($('<td></td>').text(user.dialed_number ? user.dialed_number : '{dialed_number}'))
   .append($('<td></td>').html(user && user.admin ? '<span class="textgreen">admin</span>' : 'guest'))
   .append($('<td></td>').append(_talking(user.mute ? user.mute : 0)))
   .append($('<td></td>').append($('<span></span>').addClass('timer').text(user.duration ? user.duration : '')))
   .append($('<td></td>').addClass('nowrap').append(_userButtons(user)))
;
alert( row.find('td').size() );    // = alerts 6 when it should be 7

$('#foo > tbody').append(row);
```